# How to get the whole cluster information in azure databricks at the runtime?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, databricks-connect, databricks-community-edition

The below code was working for the older version and the version has changed the code is not working in databricks.

Latest Version :12.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.3.1, Scala 2.12)

dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().tags()

what is the alteranative for this code?

Error:py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public scala.collection.immutable.Map com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext.tags() is not whitelisted on class class com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext

Comment: What older version is the above code working fine for?

Answer (score 2):

You can get most of cluster info directly from Spark config:

```
%scala
val p = "spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags."
spark.conf.getAll
  .collect{ case (k, v) if k.startsWith(p) => s"${k.replace(p, "")}: $v" }
  .toList.sorted.foreach(println)

%python
p = "spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags."
conf = [f"{k.replace(p, '')}: {v}" for k, v in spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll() if k.startswith(p)]
for l in sorted(conf): print(l)

[...]
clusterId: 0123-456789-0abcde1
clusterLastActivityTime: 1676449848620
clusterName: test
clusterNodeType: Standard_F4s_v2
[...]
```

Comment: My Admin provided access to use only python.Do you have any python code for that?

Comment: Can be also done in Python, I added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following cluster with DBS runtime of 12.0 as shown below:

[image]

- The above command has given the output as required without any error:

[image]

- But if it is the cluster information that you need, then you can use `Clusters 2.0` API. The following code would work:

```
import requests
import json

my_json = {"cluster_id": spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterId")}    

auth = {"Authorization": "Bearer <your_access_token>"}

response = requests.get('https://<workspace_url>/api/2.0/clusters/get', json = my_json, headers=auth).json()
print(response)
```

[image]

Comment: print(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().tags()) this command is throwing an error.Could you please check

Comment: i dont have access token is there any alteranative approach to get the whole cluster information at run time

Comment: The print is working fine as well (didn't include image as there is a lot of sensitive information). Try the solution given by @Kombajn zbożowy if you do not have access token.

Comment: do we need to add any configuration ,for me still i am facing the issue

Comment: Not Sure as I'm not at all facing the error. What cluster details do you need for your requirement?

Comment: Here is the cluster details that i am using Databricks Run time version:12.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.3.1, Scala 2.12)

Comment: I meant what details are you trying to get?

Comment: At run time which user is executing ? which language the code was written? notebook path?  clusterid?  clustername?   api_url? notebook_path? so at run time we need this info

Comment: How to find the databricks notebookid do you have any command?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not way to programmatically get the notebook id